# Change the string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In my webpage having two text box, If i enter "11, welcome street" then move on to next textbox means that string automatically change to "11,WELCOME ST".  using Javascript.. Please anyone help.

Thanks for advance

```
"11, welcome street"
```

I'd like to change my string to

```
"11,WELCOME ST"
```

Comment: This isn't a question - it's a specification.  At which point of this are you stuck?

Comment: there is some thing new it's called Google !

Answer (score 0):

You could do this like so

```
str.toUpperCase().replace(', ', ',').replace('STREET', 'ST')
```

Please be aware this code is brittle and can only be applied in the specific example you have requested.

Comment: I want to change value in textbox itself.. if i press tab key or choose next box means that operation will be happen...

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work as intended, even though I'd be careful about the replacement parts. Chances are, at some point you replace something you actually want to keep.

```js
alert("11, welcome street".replace("street", "ST").toUpperCase().replace(", ", ","));
```

Update: Included the "street" replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Using js:

```js
var dic = {
  "STREET": "ST",
  "ROAD": "RD",
  "JUNCTION": "JN"
};

var up = function(box) {
  box.value = box.value.toUpperCase();
  for (var k in dic)
    box.value = box.value.replace(k, dic[k])
};
```

```html
<input type='text' value='HEY' onblur='up(this)' />
```

OR

Using js:

```js
var dic = {
  "STREET": "ST",
  "ROAD": "RD",
  "JUNCTION": "JN"
};

var up = function(box) {
  var arr = box.value.toUpperCase().split(' ');
  var i = arr.length;
  while(i --)
    arr[i] = dic[arr[i]] || arr[i];
  box.value = arr.join(' ');
};
```

```html
<input type='text' value='HEY' onblur='up(this)' />
```

Comment: I have one more doubt... If i enter "street" means change to "st" and "road" change to "rd" and "junction" change to "jn"... how it put all in single function